# LINQ: How can i query a string?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

How can i query the following string, to extract information from it?

```
<Glyphs  
Fill="#ff000000" 
FontUri="\Documents\1\Resources\Fonts\547B9B52-1992-40E2-BBAA-0D815B2C6215.odttf" FontRenderingEmSize="10" 
StyleSimulations="BoldItalicSimulation" 
OriginX="20" 
OriginY="1094.96" 
UnicodeString="SomeString" />
```

For example, how can i read the OriginY value with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            string s = @"<Glyphs  
Fill=""#ff000000"" 
FontUri=""\Documents\1\Resources\Fonts\547B9B52-1992-40E2-BBAA-0D815B2C6215.odttf"" FontRenderingEmSize=""10"" 
StyleSimulations=""BoldItalicSimulation"" 
OriginX=""20"" 
OriginY=""1094.96"" 
UnicodeString=""SomeString"" />";

            double val = (double)XElement.Parse(s).Attribute("OriginY");
            Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Answer (score 2):

The string you got looks a lot like XML. You might therefore want to try LINQ to XML. For instance, use the `XDocument` class:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Glyphs  
    Fill=""#ff000000"" 
    FontUri=""...."" FontRenderingEmSize=""10"" 
    StyleSimulations=""BoldItalicSimulation"" 
    OriginX=""20"" 
    OriginY=""1094.96"" 
    UnicodeString=""SomeString"" />");

var fill = doc.Root.Attribute("Fill");
```